# Cover image resizing on different screen sizes - a problem

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a cover image that looks like a frame on my Wordpress website, but when the screen size changes it changes the location of the image frame, so it goes over my menu text.

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbDMj.jpg

My question is: how can I set the cover image to stay the same on every screen size, so it won't go over my menu and text and yet to stay always fullscreen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use vendor prefix before background-size\

```
     `-webkit-background-size:cover;
     -moz-background-size:cover;
     -o-background-size:cover;
      background-size:cover;
```